# Exporting a build from Unity to Android fails

Tags: android, macos, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality

I'm new to coding and to Unity. I've followed the step-by-step found [in this google page](https://developers.google.com/vr/unity/get-started-android#download_the_necessary_files). I have installed all the SDKs and the latest versions of Unity and Android Studio for mac OS.

Everything goes according to plan and I get to the final "run and build". It connects fine to my Note 3 and runs almost to the end when I get the following errors:

Error message window
[image: Error message window]

```
Assets/GoogleVR/Scripts/VRDevices/GvrDevice.cs(99,10): warning CS0618: `UnityEngine.GL.IssuePluginEvent(int)' is obsolete: `IssuePluginEvent(eventID) is deprecated. Use IssuePluginEvent(callback, eventID) instead.'
```

and

```
CommandInvokationFailure: Unable to convert classes into dex format. See the Console for details. /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
-Xmx2048M -Dcom.android.sdkmanager.toolsdir="/Users/Bruno.Vilela/Library/Android/sdk/tools"
-Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -jar "/Applications/Unity/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/Tools/sdktools.jar"
-
```

I have tried all that I am able to and have found no way around this. I am simply not versed enough in C# to debug this on my own. Any help will be greatly appreciated!!

SPECS:
Macbook Pro running OS X 10.10.5
Unity 5.3.4f1 Personal
Android Studio 2.1.1
Galaxy Note 3 running Android 5.0

Cheers!!

-BV

Comment: What plugins are you using? List them all with the versions. I may be able find which jar pr arr file is duplicated.

Comment: Thanks for replying! I took the time to try and understand and, hopefully, solve the problem. My level of expertise is simply not up to par yet.

I did a clean uninstall of Unity, making sure I grabbed all scattered files created in users/shared, library, and temp folders. I did it because I had previously used the, now deprecated, CardboardSDKForUnity.unitypackage and wanted to make sure it wasn't causing the conflict.

Comment: Then I proceeded to do a fresh install and brought in only the latest GoogleVRForUnity.unitypackage SDK file, published yesterday after the Google I/O revealing of the Daydream initiative. As far as I understand, the only plugins that I'm using in the file are the ones brought in by the SDK file. They appear in the plugins folder as Android, iOS, x86, and x86_64. I have tried to find their respective versions but can't locate the information. Each of these platform folders have a number of actual plugin files. Maybe you are referring to those?

Comment: I tried repeating the Run& Build process and got the same "can't convert classes into dex" error message.

I am sure that I am missing something. Thank you for helping a brother out.

Cheers!

Comment: PS. Where are the .jar files that are related to this problem stored? A general search for those files yield too many options. Cheers!

Comment: You spent time writing those without even answering my question. Open your Project file and search from Assets folder down .Search for files with .jar or .arr and report how many of them you have.Those are plugins that could be causing the problem.

Comment: Sorry man. I am new to this and wanted to make sure I expressed my effort in trying to solve this. I will be brief in the future.

I did as suggested and came up with the following:
• gvr_audio.jar
• gvr_audio.jar.meta
• gvr_android_common.aar
• gvr_android_common.aar.meta

Comment: @ok. Not much. Since this is a simple project, zip the project folder and upload it somewhere. Put a link to it here and I will run it myself to determine which one is causing the problem.

Comment: Complete List:
gvr_audio.jar, gvr_audio.jar.meta, gvr_android_common.aar, gvr_android_common.aar.meta, unitygvractivity.aar, unitygvractivity.aar.meta

Comment: Thanks man! Here's the link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-YbrhETIodqNkVKRFZ2QXdYTG8/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Tried it. The first one was able to build without problems. The one under the __MACOSX folder failed to build. I suggest you  delete all the plugins and re-import them again.

Comment: I'l try that again. Thanks @Programmer!

Answer (score 0):

This might be caused due to having duplication jar files in your project. check if that is true, try removing any duplication and building the project again.

some similar reference : http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/765961/multiple-plugin-conflict.html

Comment: Thanks for the tip CloudSL!

Do you think it may be related to the deprecation of IssuePluginEvent as mentioned in the first error?

Comment: No, the IssuePluginEvent is a warning, not an error.

Comment: Forgot to say, the most common reason for the "unable to convert files into dex format" error is indeed duplicate .jars.  See the upgrade instructions for the SDK on the google web page (see Release Notes).